# django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword)

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, and will appreciate if anyone can help me in its configuration.
I want to use my oracle db in settings.py file.
I made some changes into it by looking into tnsnames.ora.
Below are my changes :

```
tnsnames.ora

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Kathayat)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 

settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME' : 'XE',
        'USER' : 'SYSTEM',
        'PASSWORD' : 'password',
        'HOST' : 'Kathayat',
        'PORT' : 1521,
    }
}
```

After running python manage.py migrate  i am getting the error :

django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword)